# how to write test class for batch class?

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, unit-test

can any one give the sample test class for this code i am not awareness in testing please help me.

```
global class SearchAndUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Schedulable{

   global final String Query;
   public Set<String> LstString = new Set<String>();
   Public List<Demand__c> Lst1 = new list<Demand__c>();
   Public List<IDC_Demand__c> IDCDemandlst = new list<IDC_Demand__c>();

   global SearchAndUpdate()
   {      
      Query = 'Select Id,RRD_Number__c,idc_chek__c FROM Demand__c';             
      IDCDemandlst = [Select RRD_Number__c FROM IDC_Demand__c];
      if(IDCDemandlst.size()>0)
      {
          for(IDC_Demand__c IDCD : IDCDemandlst)
          {
              LstString.add(IDCD.RRD_Number__c);
          }     
      }       
   }

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
   { 
      return Database.getQueryLocator(Query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Demand__c> Lst)
   {
     if(Lst.size()>0)
     {
         for(Demand__c d : Lst)
         {
            if(LstString.contains(d.RRD_Number__c))
            {
                d.idc_chek__c= 'Yes';
                Lst1.add(d);
            }
            else if(!LstString.contains(d.RRD_Number__c))
            {
                d.idc_chek__c= 'No';
                Lst1.add(d);
            }
         }
     }
     if(Lst1.size()>0)update Lst1;
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)
    {
        SearchAndUpdate obj = new SearchAndUpdate();
        database.executeBatch(obj);
    }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to read below link it helps you
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apex_workbook/Content/apex_batch_2.htm